# How to disable database in PlayFramework

Tags: java, playframework

I'd like to totally disable it and not use the in memory database. When I delete the attributes, play complains that database is not defined. Any help?

@68ajai6kn
Can't start in PROD mode with errors

> JPA error A JPA error occurred (Cannot start a JPA manager without a
>   properly configured database): No datasource configured
>
> play.exceptions.JPAException: Cannot start a JPA manager without a
>   properly configured database  at
>   play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.onApplicationStart(JPAPlugin.java:108)  at
>   play.plugins.PluginCollection.onApplicationStart(PluginCollection.java:425)
>     at play.Play.start(Play.java:495)   at play.Play.init(Play.java:292)
>     at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:158) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: No datasource configured  ... 5 more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have any classes that are defined with `@Entity`, Play will automatically create the db connections, and in the case of the in memory db, it will start it as well.

So, to prevent the error, you need to remove all `@Entity` references.